# Override CTRL-HANDLERS windows C

Tags: c, windows, winapi, msdn

I have a server in C on Windows 10.
Now i need to catch CTRL-BREAK signal and when arrives to start a function and nothing else.
Now, i wrote this:

```
{ //some other code here
while(1) {
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(CtrlHandler, TRUE);
  }
}

BOOL WINAPI CtrlHandler(DWORD fdwCtrlType){
  if (fdwCtrlType == CTRL_BREAK_EVENT) {
    restart();
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

Now microsoft says: "if no other control handlers have been registered or none of the registered handlers returns TRUE, the default handler will be used, resulting in the process being terminated. "

But when i send a CTRL_BREAK_EVENT (ctrl + pause) the system calls the restart() function but also close the process that catch the signal.
So it execute the my CtrlHandler function but also the default handler.

How can i disable/override the default handler ? Thank You

Comment: The session server (csrss.exe) creates a new thread in the process that executes `CtrlRoutine` in kernelbase.dll, which walks the list of registered handlers until one returns `TRUE` (i.e. handled). Otherwise it continues to the default handler that calls `ExitProcess`. So what you've implemented should be working -- for this particular process. But note that every process that's attached to the console is sent the control-break event. Is the parent of your server process attached to the console? Does it maybe use a kill-on-close job object or implement something similar to that?

Comment: @ErykSun Actually the code i posted is in the "main process", it has no parents only children... it has 2 children and i noticed that when i send the ctrl+break both get closed.

Comment: Every process has a parent. There's no issue with the parent killing the child if the parent is CMD or PowerShell, since they ignore Ctrl+Break. Does your process exit if its child processes die? Experiment by terminating the child processes manually using the task manager.

Comment: The while(1) loop is odd, you need to call it only once and you'd typically do so at the start of main().  Be sure to read the docs for the HandlerRoutine callback, it does point out that the process will always be terminated, no matter what you do.  So it is really only good enough to do some critical cleanup before the process is aborted.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok i put it out the loop, that's the thing, i want to terminate the process but i also need to clean some stuff before do it... but exactly where did you read that the process will always be terminated? I read the DOC and didnt find this thing. Thanks

Comment: @ErykSun No, the server remain on if all the children die. Tested manually and with the ctrl+break ( only the children die )

Comment: The docs [are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine).  The Remarks section describe the three things you'd consider doing, all three lead to process termination.

Comment: @HansPassant, the process *is not* unconditionally terminated for Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Break events. That's only for Ctrl+Close, Ctrl+Logoff, and Ctrl+Shutdown. Commonly it's a Ctrl+Close, either from the user closing the window, or some program sending `WM_CLOSE` to the console. Since Vista, clients cannot keep the console from closing. They're given 5 seconds (default) to exit gracefully, either directly or by returning `FALSE` to let the default handler exit. Otherwise the session server (csrss.exe) kills the process forcefully via `TerminateProcess`.

Comment: @LorenzoDiGiacomo, does your server process read from console input? If so it may be exiting normally because the canceled read looks like EOF. The details depend on the version of Windows and the CRT/WINAPI functions you're using. In particular, Microsoft broke their software contract in Windows 8+, since `ReadFile` no longer sets `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED` for this case, and they haven't bothered to fix it in years. Use `ReadConsoleW` instead, which still 'works' -- as well as it ever did, at least, since the silly thing 'succeeds' with a serious last error set (canceled I/O).

Comment: @ErykSun I don't read from Console.... BUT i solved, you gave me a nice tip in the second post, i just added an handler to the child process that handles the CTRL+BREAK and returns TRUE. So the problem was that the signals arrive to all process.

Comment: @LorenzoDiGiacomo, how the child handles the control event is generally unrelated to the parent. The session server injects a separate thread in each client process, which independently executes the system `CtrlRoutine` function in each process, which independently traverses the registered control handlers in each process. If the default handler executes in the child process, it simply calls `ExitProcess(STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT)` in that process. So you have a mystery left to explain if externally killing the child via Task Manager does not cause the parent to die.

Comment: Look into the exit status code and how the child process gets terminated with the Task Manager experiment. For example, does it own top-level windows to which Task Manager sends `WM_CLOSE` in order to initiate a graceful shutdown? Or is Task Manager killing it forcefully via `TerminateProcess` with an exist status of 1? If so, try manually terminating it with `STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT` instead of 1, in order to replicate the failure condition. Or modify the child to manually call `ExitProcess(STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT)`, without a clean shutdown.